# How we notify our user to update their enterprise app

Tags: ios, notifications, version, enterprise

I m a iOS Developer. I m new in this field. I m working on an App which is for an enterprise company.

I m little bit confuse that, how we give update notification to user if we upload new version of app on our website not on AppStore because i m using Distribution of Enterprise Application through a website. i upload link there and employees download apps from that link.
Now i want to make new version of that app then what will i do that my previous version users receive notification to update old app to new app.

Plz guide me

Comment: You can use push notification for that

Comment: Push Notification is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 principal ways:

1. Email - it's an enteprise application, you should now the emails of your employees
   (not everybody uses email on their iPades, sometimes they can forget about emails)
2. Push notification (they can be disabled and suffer from the same problems as emails - it's only an alert that can be dismissed and forgotten)
3. **In-App checking** - the application should check by itself if it has the latest version installed and ask the user frequently to update or even block the usage of the app if not updated (if the use case makes sense). This works best with a push notification and also with email for major updates (to inform users about new features).

Answer (score 0):

you can notify all your app user by using Push Notification.

Answer (score 0):

1. Obviously you can use the push notifications only if you have implemented them in your previous version of the app which is already there in the devices. If not implemented then you can't use push notifications for this purpose.
2. If not, then my suggestion is that you can manually inform them through mail and implement the push notifications in this version. So that you can use the same for new version to notify them.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we send email of updation to all employees to update the app but what is the process or line of code to that when employee download the app from link then previous app updated into new app